# how to use multiple table in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

> i have this query which i need to use in laravel. I don't how can i use these tables in model and controller.

```
select  mon,year,
        combo,
       registered,
       forwardedbycmo,
       clarification,
       noaction,
       disposed,mon_srno,undertaken
from monthly_activities
union
select extract('month' from actiondate) as mon,extract('year' from actiondate) as year,
        extract('year' from actiondate)|| '-' ||to_char(to_timestamp (extract('month' from actiondate)::text, 'MM'), 'TMMon') as combo,
       sum(case when actioncode = '00' then 1 else 0 end) as registered,
       sum(case when actioncode = '4T' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as forwardedbycmo,
       sum(case when actioncode = '4D' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as clarification,
       sum(case when actioncode = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as noaction,
       sum(case when actioncode = '50' then 1 else 0 end) as disposed,null as mon_srno,
        sum(case when actioncode = '40' and fromorg='CMOFF' then 1 else 0 end) as undertaken

from actionhistory where extract(month from actiondate)=extract(month from current_date)
and extract(year from actiondate)=extract(year from current_date)
 group by mon,year order by year,mon;
";
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted so that question can be marked as closed in stack overfow. Thanks

Comment: but am facing problem in this query should i add a another question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Latest larevel Docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)
For a head start. You need to define your tables in Laravel as plural snake_case and models will be created in sigular camelCase.

So for instance, you need to create model:

`php artisan make:model monthlyActivity`

for monthly_activities table and so on...

Then you have various ways to execute query, either raw or Laravel made.
Put some time and effort and then if you get stucked , post a  more exact question to get help.
Thanks,

Comment: @Nisha Garg, Please mark the answer as accepted so that question can be marked as closed in stack overfow. Thanks